# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un json a DataTable Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

quisiera saber como pasar un atributo de un objeto en la propiedad columns del datatable por ejemplo tip:{nom} al columns del datatable y además un dato fijo

```
tablaListado=$("#tablajquery").DataTable({
          "data":consulta,
          "columns":[
              {"data":"codPro"},
              {"data":"nom"},
              {"data":"frg"},
              {"data":"tip":{"nom"}},<= error
              {"data":"2"}<=error
          ]
        })
```

json

```
{
    "cod": "00",
    "obj": [
        {
            "codPro": 1,
            "nom": "Startup 1",
            "des": "",
            "frg": 1553618417926,
            "res": {
                "codUsu": 1,
                "nom": "Jorge Romaní"
            },
            "tip": {
                "codTpr": 7,
                "nom": "Fast Track"
            },
            "est": {
                "codEst": 1,
                "nom": "Pendiente"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

mi tabla

```
<table
            class="table table-hover table-stripped table-bordered"
            cellspacing="0"
            id="tablajquery"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fecha Registro</th>
                <th>Tipo Proyecto</th>
                <th>Dias Transcurridos</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody >
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas declarar las columnas asi:

```js
var consulta = {
    "cod": "00",
    "obj": [
        {
            "codPro": 1,
            "nom": "Startup 1",
            "des": "",
            "frg": 1553618417926,
            "res": {
                "codUsu": 1,
                "nom": "Jorge Romaní"
            },
            "tip": {
                "codTpr": 7,
                "nom": "Fast Track"
            },
            "est": {
                "codEst": 1,
                "nom": "Pendiente"
            }
        }
    ]
};

tablaListado=$("#tablajquery").DataTable({
          "data":consulta.obj,
          "columns":[
              {"data":"codPro"},
              {"data":"nom"},
              {"data":"frg"},
              {"data":"tip.nom"},
              {"data":""}
          ],
          "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 4,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "2"
        } ]
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<table
            class="table table-hover table-stripped table-bordered"
            cellspacing="0"
            id="tablajquery"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fecha Registro</th>
                <th>Tipo Proyecto</th>
                <th>Dias Transcurridos</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody >
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: Gracias, estimado.